# ArgumentException: Either orderId or origClientOrderId must be sent

Tags: c#

Hi I'm working on Binance API for getting data but I'm not able to get data from getorder api. Link for APi (https://github.com/sonvister/Binance).
I've attached a image of error I'm getting as not aware of this issue.

```cs
public void Binance()
{
    sqlConnection Conn = new sqlConnection();
    Conn.LoadConnection();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Loaded.");
    var apiClient = new ApiClient(apiKey, secretKey);
    var binanceClient = new BinanceClient(apiClient); 
    var AllSymbol = binanceClient.GetAllPrices();

    foreach (var symbol in AllSymbol.Result)
    {  
        var Orders = binanceClient.GetOrder("BNBBTC").Result;
        DataTable ltblAskOrdersHistory = 
        Orders.Asks.ToList().ToDataTable();
        DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Symbol", typeof(string));
        column.DefaultValue = symbol.Symbol;
        ltblAskOrdersHistory.Columns.Add(column);
        Conn.CreateTable("tbBinanceAskOrder");
        Conn.ImportRecordsToTable(ltblAskOrdersHistory, "tbBinanceAskOrder");
        Console.WriteLine("Ask Orders Table Updated.");
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198690/discussion-on-question-by-nishtha-tarini-argumentexception-either-orderid-or-or).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it as:

```
var Orders = binanceClient.GetAllOrders(symbol.Symbol).Result;
            if (Orders.Count() > 0)
            {
                DataTable ltblOrders = Orders.ToList().ToDataTable();
                Conn.CreateTable("tbBinanceOrder");
                Conn.ImportRecordsToTable(ltblOrders, "tbBinanceOrder");
                Console.WriteLine("tbBinanceOrder Table Updated.");
            }
```